# Bizarre Thrift/PHP Performance Issue

Tags: performance, thrift

I've got a bizarre performance issue with Thrift 0.8 for PHP for both server and client. I've got two tests using a simple echo() server call that just returns the string you send to it.

- Test 1: open() the transport, Call echo() 5 times and close() the transport.
- Test 2: Loop 5 times: open() transport, call echo(), close() transport.

What? Test 2 is opening and closing the socket for each call? That must be really slow!

That's what is bizarre: Test 2 is 40x faster than Test 1, about 1ms per iteration vs 40ms per iteration.

Here is the basic idea.

```
$socket = new TSocket($host);
$transport = new TBufferedTransport($socket, 1024, 1024);
$protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);

// Test 2: Open and close the connection each time. 
function testSingleCall($c, $transport, $protocol) {
    $client = new \thrift\LocationsClient($protocol, $protocol);
    $t1 = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $transport->open();
        $v = $client->echoMessage($i);              
       $transport->close();
   }
   $t2 = microtime(true);

    return (($t2 - $t1) * 1000) / $c; // miliseconds per call
}

// Test 1: multiple calls per transaction. 
function testMultipleCall($c, $transport, $protocol) {
    $client = new \thrift\LocationsClient($protocol, $protocol);

    $t1 = microtime(true);

    $transport->open();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $v = $client->echoMessage($i);         
    }
    $transport->close();
   $t2 = microtime(true);

    return (($t2 - $t1) * 1000) / $c; // miliseconds per call
```

}

Any ideas what would cause opening and closing sockets to be faster than re-using the open socket?

Update: The slowness is during reading the message header, TBinaryProtocol::readMessageBegin(). The first call after opening the transport is fast ( < 1ms) while all subsequent calls on the same opened transport are very slow ( 38ms )